# Orientdb SELECT and subqueries with aggregate

Tags: orientdb

I have a generic class invoices with columns of `dateTime`, `invoice`, `customer`, `amount`. In a day there are 100's of invoices.

I want to write a query to get the `invoice,customer` whose amount is max for the day. So this would be report for a week with one daily record of the invoice which was the highest in that day.

Have tried something, but it yields no results.

```
SELECT FROM Invoices
LET $a = (
  SELECT dateTime as maxdateTime, max(amount) as maxInvoice
  FROM Invoices GROUP BY dateTime
)
where amount = maxAmount and dateTime = maxdateTime
```

Comment: please, remember to take your time and properly format your question before posting. Welcome to SO.

Comment: Which version of OrientDB are you using?